# In particle edit of hair, how to move hair root without getting away from the mesh

Tags: particles, hair

After unchecking the preserve of root position, I can move the particle root vertex with g, how ever it easily get off from the surface and may be inside or outside. How can I move the root but let it remain at the surface?

Comment: hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: [Snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html) to faces works for the hair strands. But it looks like you can't limit the snapping to the root.  As a result, the hair shrinkwraps to the mesh and you have to comb it again.